# Assign values in Action list?

Tags: c#, generics, nunit

i had a null value error in my test class

```
[Test]
    public void when_send_the_command_it_execute_correct_command_handler()
    {
        //Arrange
        var commandBus = new CommandBus();
        ICommand commandforsend=null;
        IMetaData metaDataforsend=null;

        Action<ICommand, IMetaData> fakeHandler = (fakecommand, fakemetadata) =>
        {
            commandforsend = fakecommand;
            metaDataforsend = fakemetadata;
        };
```

commandforsend and metaDataforsend values are still null
what can happen ? help me thank you !

Comment: You just defined your Action, did not execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an `Action` but you are never calling it. Your code is equivalent to a separate method that assigns the values but that you don't call so the code inside the method never runs.

If you want to execute the `fakeHandler` you should add the following line below the declaration:

```
fakeHandler(aFakeCommand, aFakeMetadata);`
```

As you can see, this is the same as calling a regular method. You need to supply values for both parameters (`fakecommand` and `fakemetadata`).

You can find more info in the [MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: please give me more details for  execute the fakeHandler. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since your code doesn't execute `fakeHandler`, this behavior is OK, because you've just declared a anonymous method without executing it.